# Pack table option in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I write a code pack all table in Map Window, after pack all table, some tables are removed from map window,

How do I known which table is pack, and open table to map window in the order as original layer.

Comment: Before packing the tables, you could get a list of all tables in the map window and add them back after packing.

Comment: Thank you. But can open table sort in order as first, or only open tables was packed. And print message table was packed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compaire the number of rows before and after pack of table

```
Print "Before: " + TableInfo("MyTable", TAB_INFO_NROWS)
'Pack table here
Print "After: " + TableInfo("MyTable", TAB_INFO_NROWS)
```